# Returning unique values from multiple data attributes

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following markup:

```
<li data-group="bottoms">Pants</li>
<li data-group="bottoms">Pants</li>
<li data-group="bottoms">Pants</li>
<li data-group="tops">Shirt</li>
<li data-group="tops">T-shirt</li>
<li data-group="tops">Polo</li>
<li data-group="accessories">Sunglasses</li>
```

Im trying to return a list of the unique `data-group` names, but I only wanna return it once. Which means from the list above I would like to return a variable that will contain:

- bottoms
- tops
- accessories

My approach to this is to first find the length of the list and then make a for loop which loops over all the elements and prints their `data-group` value. After that I would have to do some sorting so that the bottoms and tops dont show up 3 times, but only once.

I have tried to write the initial code which looks like this.

```
var uniqueCategoryGroupNames = document.querySelectorAll('li[data-group]');

for (var k = 0; k < uniqueCategoryGroupNames.length; k++) {
    console.log([k]);
    uniqueCategoryGroupNames[k].getAttribute('data-group');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`Array#from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
liArray.reduce(                                       //Go through your Array
  (acc, curr) => 
    acc.includes(curr.getAttribute('data-group')) ?   // Is the current value already stored?
      acc                                             // Then don't add the current value
      : acc.concat([curr.getAttribute('data-group')]) // Else add the value
  , []                                                // Starting value for the accumulator
);
```

---

***Demo:***

```js
let liArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li[data-group]'));

let result = liArray.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.includes(curr.getAttribute('data-group')) ? acc : acc.concat([curr.getAttribute('data-group')]), []);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-group="bottoms">Pants</li>
  <li data-group="bottoms">Pants</li>
  <li data-group="bottoms">Pants</li>
  <li data-group="tops">Shirt</li>
  <li data-group="tops">T-shirt</li>
  <li data-group="tops">Polo</li>
  <li data-group="accessories">Sunglasses</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a array to store that attributes and check for the existence of the attribute before pushing it into the array:

```js
var uniqueCategoryGroupNames = document.querySelectorAll('li[data-group]');
var res = [];
for (var k = 0; k < uniqueCategoryGroupNames.length; k++) {
var attr = uniqueCategoryGroupNames[k].getAttribute('data-group');
  //check that the attribute do not exist in the array
  if(res.indexOf(attr) === -1) {
    res.push(attr);
  }
}
console.log(res);
```

```html
<li data-group="bottoms">Pants</li>
<li data-group="bottoms">Pants</li>
<li data-group="bottoms">Pants</li>
<li data-group="tops">Shirt</li>
<li data-group="tops">T-shirt</li>
<li data-group="tops">Polo</li>
<li data-group="accessories">Sunglasses</li>
```

Comment: @Sun yes it is far better than using `reduce` and `filter` which OP has accepted

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use new `Set` object (which stores only unique values) or use old plain object. Also you can use [`dataset` if you support browsers IE11+](https://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset) (otherwise just replace `dataset` with `getAttribute('data-group')`)

**Using `Set`**

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li[data-group]');
var uniqueGroupsSet = Array.from(lis).reduce((all, li) => all.add(li.dataset.group), new Set());
var uniqueGroupNames = Array.from(uniqueGroupsSet);
```

**Using plain object**

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li[data-group]');
var uniqueGroupsSet = Array.from(lis).reduce((all, li) => {
  all[li.dataset.group] = true
  return all
}, {});
var uniqueGroupNames = Object.keys(uniqueGroupsSet);
```

**Combined way**: plain object + array

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li[data-group]');
var uniqueGroupNames = []
Array.from(lis).reduce((all, li) => {
  if (!all[li.dataset.group]) {
    all[li.dataset.group] = true
    uniqueGroupNames.push(li.dataset.group)
  }
  return all
}, {});
console.log(uniqueGroupNames)
```